# Pass array of data in angularjs multipart

Tags: arrays, angularjs, image, upload

I have an array of colors and sizes, and some other data like product_name and images, I am able to send image files and product_name but when I attach color_and_sizes array then it says 500 error

Here is my Code :(Angularjs and Laravel Controller )
Basically I want to save all the details in the database but I am unable to save the color and sizez details.

```js
$scope.admin_add_product=function(){
   var product_name=$scope.txtProductname;
   var product_description=$scope.tarDescription;
   var price=$scope.txtprice;
   var unit_in_stock=$scope.txtunitinstock;
   var unit_weight=$scope.txtweight;
   var file = $scope.front_image;
   var file2=$scope.back_image;
   var file3=$scope.left_side_image;
   var file4=$scope.right_side_image;
   var main_image=$scope.main_image;
   var large_image=$scope.large_image;
   var category_id=$scope.selectedCategory.category_id;
   var sub_category_id=$scope.selectedSubCategory.sub_category_id;
   var sub_sub_category_id=$scope.selectedSubSubCategory.sub_sub_category_id;
   var product_key=$scope.addProductOption;
   var tags=$scope.txt_tags;
   var aditional_information=$scope.txt_aditional_information;
   var temp_color_and_size=[];
   temp_color_and_size=$scope.color_and_size;
   console.log(temp_color_and_size);
   var uploadUrl = 'http://web.com/app/add_product';
   fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file,file2,file3,file4,main_image,large_image, product_name,product_description,price,category_id,sub_category_id,sub_sub_category_id,unit_in_stock,unit_weight,product_key,tags,aditional_information ,temp_color_and_size, uploadUrl);
   
 }
  
  /* ---------------------------------------------------- Color and Sizes -------------------------------------------------- */
   $scope.color_and_size=[];
   $scope.Add=function(){
    var c_and_s=[];
    c_and_s.color_name = document.getElementById('cl1').value;
    var s;
    if($scope.sizes!=null)
    {
     for(var i=0;i<$scope.sizes.length-1;i++)
     {
      if($scope.sizes[i+1]>=0 && $scope.sizes[i+1]<=9)
      {
       
      }
      else
      {
       if($scope.sizes[i+2]>=0 && $scope.sizes[i+2]<=9)
       {
        
       }
       else
       {
        $scope.sizes = $scope.sizes.substring(0, i+1);
       }
      }
     }
     console.log($scope.sizes);
     $scope.size=$scope.sizes.split(',');
     c_and_s.sizes=$scope.size;
    }
    $scope.color_and_size.splice(0,0,c_and_s);
    console.log($scope.color_and_size);
    document.getElementById('cl1').value="#000000";
    $scope.sizes="";
   }
      
      
      myApp.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
     this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file,file2,file3,file4,main_image,large_image,product_name,product_description,price,category_id,sub_category_id,sub_sub_category_id,unit_in_stock,unit_weight,product_key,tags,aditional_information,temp_color_and_size, uploadUrl){
  console.log(product_name);
  console.log(product_description);
  console.log(price);
  console.log(unit_in_stock);
  console.log(unit_weight);
  console.log(file);
  console.log(temp_color_and_size);
  console.log(product_key);
  console.log(tags);
  console.log(aditional_information);
  
  var payload = new FormData();
  payload.append("product_name", product_name);
  payload.append('product_description', product_description);
  payload.append('price', price);
  payload.append('unit_in_stock', unit_in_stock);
  payload.append('unit_weight', unit_weight);
  payload.append('file', file);
  payload.append('file2', file2);
  payload.append('file3', file3);
  payload.append('file4', file4);
  payload.append('main_image', main_image);
  payload.append('large_image', large_image);
  payload.append('product_key', product_key);
  payload.append('tags', tags);
  payload.append('aditional_information', aditional_information);
  payload.append('temp_color_and_size', temp_color_and_size);
  
  return $http({
   url: uploadUrl,
   method: 'POST',
   data: payload,
   //assign content-type as undefined, the browser
   //will assign the correct boundary for us
   headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined},
   //prevents serializing payload.  don't do it.
   transformRequest: angular.identity
  })
  .then(function (response){
   alert('Product Added Successfully');
   window.location = "http://web.com/add_product"
     },function (error){
    
     });
 }
}]);
```

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear to me but I think the problem is that all properties of the formData object apart from temp_color_and_size are string type and temp_color_and_size is a javascript object. This might solve your problem.

```
payload.append('temp_color_and_size', JSON.stringify(temp_color_and_size);
```

You have to deserialize JSON string on the server side.

Comment: Still give POST http://web.com/app/add_product 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Can you connect me over teamviewer?

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35774898/how-to-get-data-from-formdata-in-a-php-file

Comment: @SurajKumar It depends on what the server expects for these values. It is the one throwing the error, you have to find out why.